# Identify subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with their characteristic functions

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

If $G\subseteq2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is comeager then exist is a partition $\mathbb{N}=A_0\cup A_1$, $A_0\cap A_1=\emptyset$, and sets $B_i \subseteq A_i$ for $i \in \{0,1\}$, such that for $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, if either $A\cap A_0=B_0$ or $A\cap A_1=B_1$, then $A \in G$.

How obtaining a partition of $\mathbb {N}$. A suggestion, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  The title seems unrelated to the body of the Question, and the only "question" asked in the body seems to be "How obtaining a partition of $\mathbb{N}$".  There is no $G$ defined in this context, comeager or otherwise.

Comment: Hello, hardmath I've edited the question

Comment: For clarity, you are asking if there exists a two set partition of $\mathbb{N} = A_0 \cup A_1$ which fulfills the requirement for some $G \subseteq 2^\mathbb{N}$ to be "comeager".  But you haven't told us what specifically defines $G$.  I don't think your edit addresses what I commented before.

Comment: See also cross-post at http://mathoverflow.net/q/198807/5340 "Question about of comeager set"